# Incremental Counting of Prime Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
count = 0

while True:
    number = int(input("Enter The Number: "))

    if number > 1:
        for i in range(2,int(number/2)):
            if (number % i == 0):
                print(number, "is not a Prime Number")
                break
        else:
            print(number,"is a Prime number")
            count = count + 1
    else:
        print(number,"is not a Prime number")

    print("Total number of prime number counted : {0}".format(count))
```

When user input a number, it will check if the number is prime number. If yes, it will increase the count. There is a problem with this code, if I key in 4, it increase the count by 1. 4 is not a prime number.

Been trying to figure out why will this happen but I couldn't. If I remove the count completely from the code, it is able to check that 4 is NOT a prime number.

Why is count causing this problem?

Comment: You have an indentation issue; align the indentation of the `else: print(number, "is a Prime number")` block and it should run as you intend

Comment: @THK no this is the loop termination else, not the if else. 
Btw the division by 2 is a nice optimization, but actually you only need to test factors up to and including sqrt(number), which will give you a asymptotic speedup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `number` is 4 the `range(2,int(number/2))` is equal to `range(2, 2)` and no loops executed and the code continues to `else`.

Answer (score 3):

The correct code is:

```
count = 0

while True:
    number = int(input("Enter The Number: "))

    if number > 1:
        for i in range(2,int(number/2)+1):
            if (number % i == 0):
                print(number, "is not a Prime Number")
                break
        else:
            print(number,"is a Prime number")
            count = count + 1
    else:
        print(number,"is not a Prime number")

    print("Total number of prime number counted : {0}".format(count))
```

You have to add +1 to int(number/2) because if the number is 4, the loop executes from i=2 until i<2, so, the loop doesn't start. If the loop doesn't start or if the loop is broke(by break), the else block is executed([Documentation](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-October/006155.html)).
In conclusion, when the number is 4 the else block is executed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your way of calculating if the number is prime or not, the `if` and `else` statements are correct, just change the `range` like this:

```py
count = 0

while True:
    number = int(input("Enter The Number: "))

    if number > 1:
        for i in range(2, number):
            if (number % i == 0):
                print(number, "is not a Prime Number")
                break
        else:
            print(number,"is a Prime number")
            count = count + 1
    else:
        print(number,"is not a Prime number")

    print("Total number of prime number counted : {0}".format(count))
```

Comment: Well this change gives an unnecessary 2x performance hit, when a +1 to compensate for the end parameter in range being exclusive, is sufficient.